# Mybatis + Spring Boot : @Update is not working

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to do an update using @update annotation. The query triggers fine without any exceptions but method returns 0 every time (0 row updated). No update is happening in the db. and same query is working fine from SQLdeveloper tool.
Using Oracle db.

```
 @Update(
     "UPDATE extra.EMMT SET CASE_STATUS = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS}, CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp} WHERE T_TimeStmp >= #{updateBean.LAST_T_TimeStmp} AND T_TimeStmp <= #{updateBean.T_TimeStmp} AND T_NO = #{updateBean.T_NO} AND EM_NO =  #{updateBean.EM_NO}"
     )

public long update(@Param("updateBean") EMMT updateBean);
```

"EMMT updateBean" is class has same members as the columns the table EMMT.

and I also tried creating two different sessions one for update and other is for insert, but didn't help much.

Session config.

```
@Bean(name = "updatesession")
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryupdate() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    
    
    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = factoryBean.getObject();
    sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().setJdbcTypeForNull(JdbcType.NULL);
    sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().setDefaultStatementTimeout(15);
    sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMappers("com.xyz.myapp.mapper");
    
    return sqlSessionFactory;
}
```

Using Mybatis-spring - 2.2.0

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be apricated.
Thanks.

EXAMPLE -
configuration for sqlSession is given above.

bean class.

```
 class justForUpdate {
     String CASE_STATUS;
     String EM_NO ;
     Timestamp T_TimeStmp;
     Long T_NO ;
     Timestamp CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp;
     Timestamp LAST_T_TimeStmp;
     
}
```

service class

```
    updateservice {


@Autowired
private SqlSessionFactory sessions;

        public void work() {
    
          //obj of justForUpdate = auth
         //or can pass list of justForUpdate objs.
                
            try(SqlSession session = sessions.openSession(true)){
                
                Update_mapper upd = session.getMapper(Update_mapper.class);
                
                long val = upd.update(auth);
                System.out.print(">>>>>>>>>  "+val);
                
            }
            
            }
        
        
        }
```

Update_Mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface Update_mapper {

@Update(
         "UPDATE extra.EMMT SET CASE_STATUS = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS}, CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp} WHERE T_TimeStmp >= #{updateBean.LAST_T_TimeStmp} AND T_TimeStmp <= #{updateBean.T_TimeStmp} AND T_NO = #{updateBean.T_NO} AND EM_NO =  #{updateBean.EM_NO}"
         )
    
    public long update(@Param("updateBean") EMMT updateBean);

}
```

Comment: Update of zero rows is expected when in the database there is no record fullfilling the `WHERE` predicate of the `UPDATE` statement. Here is nothing we can help with based on your information. Only can be said that if you *insert* in an other session than you *update* - and do not commit the *insert* - this is exactly what you should expect...

Comment: Hi @MarmiteBomber, Thanks for replying. But the thing is,  even for small and simple Update queries the same thing is happening.  `UPDATE extra.EMMT SET CASE_STATUS = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS} WHERE EM_NO =  #{updateBean.EM_NO} ` .. Application is executing queries fine but returns 0. I tried with single session as well, nothing helped.

Comment: Please post a *reproducible examle* otherwise no chance to assist...

Comment: Sorry, but the example must `insert` one row and than try to `update` it and fails.  You'll probably debug your problem while writing it - something with `LAST_T_TimeStmp`, `T_TimeStmp`, `T_NO` or `EM_NO` is wrong - possible one of those is `null`?

Comment: @Akif What is the data type of `T_TimeStmp`? If it's `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` with precision less than 6, you may have to cast when comparing the value. e.g. `T_TimeStmp >= CAST(#{updateBean.LAST_T_TimeStmp} AS DATE)` or `T_TimeStmp >= CAST(#{updateBean.LAST_T_TimeStmp} AS TIMESTAMP(3))`

Comment: Hey @ave, That's `Timestamp (9)`
I am using the same arrangement for `Insert` and it is working flawless.

Comment: @Akif, I would look into it if you could share a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Comment: Hi @ave, I tried to recreate it in a small project. Please have a look.
with H2 everything is working fine but when I try it with Oracle, update starts to fail.
(https://github.com/akifarfien/MyBatis-update.git)

Comment: @Akif Thanks, but the URL is 404. Is it private?

Comment: @ave https://github.com/akifarfien/MyBatis-update
Can you access it now? It's public
And please let me know you need replica from Insert fn as well.. rn it just has a update fn.

Comment: @Akif The update is executed in a different session and does not see the inserted rows, it seems. When using mybatis-spring, you don't use SqlSessionFactory. Please read the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession) and learn the basics. For multiple datasources config, this [demo](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo) may help.

Comment: Hi @ave, I tried this method but still facing the same issue.
Can you help me with it?
you try to reconfigure in the repo ?

Comment: @Akif You should copy some working demo project like the one I linked and make small changes one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might bump into this same stupid problem.

the quick fix was using "TRIM()" in my query with column name.
Some columns were defined as 40 bytes. hence containing numbers of spaces.

```
@Update(
"UPDATE extra.EMMT SET CASE_STATUS = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS}, CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp = #{updateBean.CASE_STATUS_TimeStmp} WHERE T_TimeStmp >= #{updateBean.LAST_T_TimeStmp} AND T_TimeStmp <= #{updateBean.T_TimeStmp} AND TRIM(T_NO) = #{updateBean.T_NO} AND TRIM(EM_NO) =  #{updateBean.EM_NO}")
        
    public long update(@Param("updateBean") EMMT updateBean);
    
}
```

Comment: You should only consider this as a "quick" fix but not a long-term solution. By using modified (trimmed) DB values in the WHERE clause, you are preventing the DB engine from using indexes. It will perform a full table scan for each and every update.